# Banded grid view in XHTML Strict + CSS

Tags: css, gridview, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm trying to create a simple banded grid view in XHTML Strict with CSS. For an example see [this picture of a devExpress GridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/i/features/advBandedGridView_layout.png). The main issue is how to create a table where each entry consists of multiple rows. Of course, something like

```
<table>
<tr><td>
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td width=100>Item 1, cell 1</td>
     <td width=200>Item 1, cell 2</td>
   </tr><tr>
     <td width=300>Item 1, cell 3</td>
   </tr><tr>
     <td width=150>Item 1, cell 4</td>
     <td width=150>Item 1, cell 5</td>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td width=100>Item 2, cell 1</td>
     <td width=200>Item 2, cell 2</td>
   </tr><tr>
     <td width=300>Item 2, cell 3</td>
   </tr><tr>
     <td width=150>Item 2, cell 4</td>
     <td width=150>Item 2, cell 5</td>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

However, this 'smells'. Same goes for using a lot of colspans. Are there any other options?

Comment: of course, you can build this data grid on divs, but why do you think 'this smells'? It is normal way to present complex table content.
P.S. width="300" colspan="2"?

Comment: I have to say this is a *horrible* UI, but aesthetic judgements aside I'd go with a ul substructure I think. HTML just doesn't have good support for something like this, but that says more about the structure than HTML I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also nest tables:

```
<table>
<tr><td><!----- row 1 -->
    little icon
</td><td>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Band 1</td><td>some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Band 2</td><td>some other data</td></tr>
    </table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><!----- row 2 -->
...
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an option I thought of, but since the bands have different structure, I hoped there would be a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write your own way of outputting the table (either as a method in the codebehind, or as a custom controller), with a DataTable-object or something like that as input. Don't think the standard gridview-controller is able to do what you want it to.